# Error reading file in blob storage with accent in name through pyspark/databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

Trying to read a file from blob storage in Databricks using pyspark fails if there is an accent in the name.

```
shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details.
```

Sample code:

```
container = ""
storage_account = ""
sas_token = ""

wasb_file = f"wasbs://{container}@{storage_account}.blob.core.windows.net/ávalon.json"
spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.sas.{container}.{storage_account}.blob.core.windows.net", sas_token)
spark.read.json(wasb_file)
```

If I rename the file to something without an accent (ie: avalon) it works without any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to escape that character or put it in a quote and see if it works ?
Something like below ?

```
val df = spark.read.json("abfss://{container}@{stgacc.net}/path\\{ávalon\\}.json"
```

Comment: Switching from wasb to abfs did the trick. Doing spark.read.json("abfss://{container}@{stgacc.net}/ávalon.json") worked without escaping the characters